# ListIterator previous method not working

Tags: java, iterator, listiterator

```
package wrap;
import java.util.*;
public class ArrayListDemo {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
        a.add("B");
        a.add("C");
        a.add("D");
        ListIterator<String> i=a.listIterator();
        while(i.hasPrevious()){
            System.out.println(i.previous());
        }
    }

}
```

The program works fine for hasNext() and next() methods but for hasPrevious() and previous() it displays a message as below::

```
<terminated> ArrayListDemo [Java Application] C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (28-Oct-2013 3:20:35 PM)
```

Answer (score 19):

From the doc :

```
public ListIterator<E> listIterator()
```

> Returns a list iterator over the elements in this list (**in proper
>   sequence**).

and

```
boolean hasPrevious()
```

> Returns true if this list iterator has more elements when traversing
>   the list in the reverse direction.

Because the iterator is in the first position, `hasPrevious()` will return false and hence the while loop is not executed.

```
 a's elements

    "B"  "C"  "D"
     ^
     |

Iterator is in first position so there is no previous element
```

---

If you do :

```
    ListIterator<String> i=a.listIterator(); <- in first position
    i.next(); <- move the iterator to the second position
    while(i.hasPrevious()){
        System.out.println(i.previous());
    }
```

It will print `"B"` because you're in the following situation :

---

a's elements

```
        "B"  "C"  "D"
              ^
              |
    Iterator is in second position so the previous element is "B"
```

---

You could also use the method `listIterator(int index)`. It allows you to place the iterator at the position defined by `index`.

If you do :

```
ListIterator<String> i=a.listIterator(a.size());
```

It will print

```
D
C
B
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you get the default `ListIterator` for the list, it starts with the first element, which is why `hasPrevious()` returns `false` and the `while` loop is exited. If you want to traverse the list in the reverse order, get the `ListIterator` from the last index and traverse backwards using the `hasPrevious()` and `previous()` methods.

```
ListIterator<String> i = a.listIterator(a.size()); // Get the list iterator from the last index
while (i.hasPrevious()) {
    System.out.println(i.previous());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ListIterator<String> i=a.listIterator();
```

initially iterator i will point to `index of 0`

You are at `index 0` so there is no previous element.

Answer (score 0):

It will start at the front of the list and thus nothing is before that point. If you want to use these methods, use a `ListIterator.`

[Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

Answer (score 0):

You gave to reach to the end of the list or anywhere in between to traverse back. There is no previous element to element at index 0.

Eg

```
System.out.println("Elements in forward directiton");
        while(i.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(i.next());
        }
System.out.println("Elements in backward directiton");
        while(i.hasPrevious()){
            System.out.println(i.previous());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, You pointer is still pointing to first element in List so -1 is not possible.

List of size n will have 1,2 ....n-1 as index.

n-1 is not -1.

THis is the reason why hasPrevious and previous are not working for you.

Cheers.