# previous in List Iterator of Java

Tags: java, iterator

I use the list iterator of Java, and I don't understand how does the previous method work.
I get the next element of the Linked list "B" and then I try to get the previous element "A" but I get "B".

```
LinkedList<Character> abc = new LinkedList<Character>();
abc.add('A');
abc.add('B');
ListIterator<Character> iterator = abc.listIterator();
System.out.println(iterator.next());
System.out.println(iterator.next());
System.out.println(iterator.previous());
```

The output is "A", "B", "B".

Why doesn't it work, and how does it work behind the scenes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListIterator previous method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631699/listiterator-previous-method-not-working)

Comment: @fantaghirocco That is not a duplicate of this question. That question asks why `hasPrevious` returns `false` when at the start.

Answer (score 7):

From JavaDocs:

> Returns the previous element in the list and moves the cursor position
>   backwards. This method may be called repeatedly to iterate through the
>   list backwards, or intermixed with calls to next to go back and forth.
>   (Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same
>   element repeatedly.)

Important part here is: **(Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly.)**